# How to merge lines (of a multi-line code routine)

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl, text-formatting

I have a file; contents are as follows:

`cat -n /tmp/my_file`

```
 1  verify(abc) {
 2    foo : bar;
 3    sub1(aa) {
 4    line1;
 5    } 
 6    sub2 (bb) {
 7    line1;
 8    // this line is a comment and must be ignored
 9    line2;
10       sub3 (cc) {
11       line1;
12     }
13    }  
14  }
15  
16  verify(efg) {
17    foo : bar;
18    sub1(aa) {
19    line1;
20    } 
21    sub2 (bb) {
22    line1;
23    // this line is a comment and must be ignored
24    line2;
25       sub3 (cc) {
26       line1;
27     }
28    }  
29  }
```

(Line numbers are just for illustration and are not part of the file.)

And I need to have its content converted into following format using awk or Perl:

```
verify(abc) { foo : bar; sub1 (aa) { line1; } sub2 (bb) { line1; line2; sub3 (cc) { line1; } } }

verify(efg) { foo : bar; sub1 (aa) { line1; } sub2 (bb) { line1; line2; sub3 (cc) { line1; } } }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: An end of line in Unix is character \n, so you just need to any (that is not alone on a line) with some preprocessing to remove any line starting with //. What did you try already?

Comment: Removing lines starting with // is not a problem; what algorithm should I use to ensure contents of each "verify()" routine is place on one line?

Comment: The previous comment assumes that you always have at least one empty line between two functions/subroutines, which may not be the case in your file.

Comment: I can make several observations about the blocks of code / text that you want to have compressed into single lines: (1) They are 14 lines long.  (2) They are 13 lines long, not counting comments.  (3) They are everything up to a blank line (or the end of the file).  (4) They are everything between an outermost set of matching `{` and `}`. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Which of these can we depend on to be true?

Comment: If you post your input filer without the line numbers then we'll have something we can simply copy/paste to test a potential solution against. Otherwise you're relying on us removing the line numbers and then YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner:

> awk '{ if ( NF > 0 && $1 !~ /^\/\// ) { bl=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s ", $i; }; if ( NF == 0 && bl == 1 ) {printf "\n" }; if ( NF == 0 && bl == 0 ) {bl=1; printf "\n\n" } } END { if ( bl == 0 ) { printf "\n" } } ' /tmp/my_file

Explanation:

> if ( NF > 0 && $1 !~ /^\/\// ) { bl=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s ", $i; }

if number of fields is greater than 0 and the first field is not a comment, for every field print the field and a space. The regex is actually "^//" (starts with "//") however the "/" must be escaped, therefore "\/".  Also bl=0 sets the prior blank line flag which we will use to control the end of record/blank line handle later in the statement.

Next, handle the blank lines/ end of record cases;

First, check if this is just a blank line.

> if ( NF == 0 && bl == 1 ) {printf "\n" };

if the number of fields is 0 and our prior blank line flag is set, just print a single newline.

Next, test to see if we just ended a line of data/text and need to add a line

> if ( NF == 0 && bl == 0 ) {bl=1; printf "\n\n" }

If the number of fields is 0 and the prior blank line flag is unset, set the blank line flag and print the line endings.

Finally!!!

> END { if ( bl == 0 ) { printf "\n" } }

if we finished the file, see if a end of record line ending was printed, if not do it.

Comment: I’ve been told that any answer that produces the correct results for the sample input is good enough.  And +1 for the idea of just printing the lines without newlines; it is somewhat less effort than saving them in a buffer.  But I have identified some issues with your answer: (1) Awk syntax is different from shell syntax.  In the shell, you reference variable `x` as `$x`; positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, …, ``$*`` and ``"$@"``) follow the same pattern.  In awk, you reference variable `x` as `x`; `$` is used *only* for input fields.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … So, in awk, if `x=5`, then `$x` is `$5` (the fifth input field) and not `5`. (But you know that; you’re using that convention when you say `$i`.) In particular, `$NF` is not the *number* of fields, but rather *the **last** field.* So your `if` `$NF > 0` test compares *the last field* (the last word on the line) with `0` (doing string comparison if necessary); so it will fail if the last field is a negative number, or a word beginning with `!`, `"`, `(`, `)`, `+`, or any other character that sorts before `0`. You should simply be saying `if ( NF > 0 …` and `if ( NF < 1 )`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (1a) Rather than `if ( NF < 1 )`, it’s more conventional to test `if ( NF == 0 )` (since it can’t be negative).  (2) In (most?) languages where `//` begins a comment, it does not need to be followed by a space.  So ```//this is a comment``` is a valid comment.  But awk will set `$1` to `//this`, so your test for `$1 != "//"` will give you wrong results. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Remember how `printf` works — the first argument is a format string; the following parameters are data.  If a line of the input contains a `%` (e.g., ``a = b%c;`` or ``z = y%x;``), your `printf` will choke.  You should do `printf "%s " $i`.  (4) If (as shown) the input file does not end with a blank line, then the output from your program will not end with a newline.  (5) Conversely, if the input file has seven blank lines in a row, your program will print 13 blank lines there.

Comment: Sigh, answering questions half asleep makes for mistakes. edited answer.  1) True, just a hurried mistake, 1a) switched test, == is more conventional, either works but the inverse test will throw someone 2) negative match on regex "^//" 3) good forward thinking 4)&5) added a simple flag var to prevent multiple new lines, and to include a final newline.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each block (each "verify()" routine)
begins with a line that begins with `verify`
and ends with a line that begins with `}`
(and that no line *within* a routine begins with `}`),
and that the white space is all spaces:

#### ex

```
printf '%s\n' 'g|^ *//|d' 'g/^verify/.,/^}/j' x | ex -- /tmp/my_file
```

Edit the file with `ex` (the command-line version of `vi` / `vim`).

- `g|^ *//|d` looks for all lines that match the regular expression `^ *//`
  (i.e., contain `//` preceded by zero or more spaces, but nothing else)
  and deletes them.
- `g/^verify/.,/^}/j` finds every line that matches the regular expression
  `^verify` (i.e., that begins with `verify`). 
  Then, for each one,
  find the first following line that matches the regular expression `^}`
  (i.e., that begins with `}`),
  and **j**oins all the lines between the `verify` and the `}`,
  inclusive, discarding extra whitespace before and after
  the newlines that are squeezed out.
- `x` saves and exits.
  **Note:** This overwrites the input file.

#### sed

```
sed -n '/^verify/ { h; d }; /^ *\/\//d; /./H; /^}/ { g; s/ *\n */ /gp }; /^$/p' /tmp/my_file
```

- `-n` — don’t print except when told to.
- `/^verify/ { h; d }` — when you see a line that begins with `verify`,
  copy it to the **h**old space and **d**elete the pattern space
  (i.e., go on to the next input line without doing any further processing).
- `/^ *\/\//d` — when you see a line
  that begins with zero or more spaces and `//`, delete it
  (i.e., go on to the next input line without doing any further processing).
- `/./H` — for any non-blank line other than the above,
  append it to the hold space.
- `/^}/ { g; s/ *\n */ /gp }` — when you see a line that begins with `}`,
  **g**et the hold space into the pattern space. 
  Then squeeze it down to a single line
  by replacing each embedded newline
  (along with preceding and following spaces)
  with a single space, and print it.
- `/^$/p` — print blank lines.

#### awk

```
awk '
    /^ *\/\//   { next; }
    /./         { buffer = buffer " " $0; }
    /^}/        { sub(/^ */, "", buffer); sub(/ *$/, "", buffer);
                  gsub(/ * /, " ", buffer); print buffer; buffer = ""; }
    /^$/        { print; }
    ' /tmp/my_file
```

- When you see a comment, skip it.
- Concatenate all other non-blank lines into `buffer`. 
  Newlines are implicitly discarded.
- When you see a line beginning with `}`,
  strip all the excess space out of `buffer`, print it, and clear it.
- Print blank lines.